# How to have one form with multiple actions

Tags: forms, codeigniter, model-view-controller, view

I have one doubt is it possible to have a single form(view page) with multiple actions like i want to save,update and delete on the same view page..if the user click on anyof the button then it have to call on a necessary controller function is it possible??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have some ways to do it, but all of the them require some javascript code.

The easiest I can think of is to dynamically change the form action when clicking each button (of type `button`, not `submit` which is the default), and then submit the form.

Example:

```
<form id="myform" name="myform" method="post" action="">
  <input id="myinput" name="myinput" type="text"/>
  [..]other inputs[/..]

  <button type="button" onClick="deleteAction()">DELETE</button>
  <button type="button" onClick="updateAction()">UPDATE</button>
  <button type="button" onClick="saveAction()">SAVE</button>
</form>
```

Where the JS functions are:

```
function deleteAction() {
    changeActionAndSubmit('/action/delete');
}

function updateAction() {
    changeActionAndSubmit('/action/update');
}

function saveAction() {
    changeActionAndSubmit('/action/save');
}

function changeActionAndSubmit(action) {
    document.getElementById('myform').action = action;
    document.getElementById('myform').submit();
}
```

Hope I got your doubt and that this solves your issue :)

Comment: changeActionAndSubmit('/action/delete'); here action is controller name???

Comment: @dhara yes, exactly

Answer (score 1):

A non-JS way to achieve the same goal would be to use the name/value parameters on each button to have your backend decide what to do.

Example

```
<?php echo form_open('controller/method'); ?>

// form fields go here

<button type="submit" name="add" value="y">press to add</button>
<button type="submit" name="update" value="y">press to update</button>
<button type="submit" name="delete" value="y">press to delete</button>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

then, on your controller, after validating user input, you can determine which button was pressed by reading what the buttons send about themselves to the controller (I'll assume you use CI's form helper)

```
if ($this->input->post('add') == 'y')
{
  // the user wants to add
}

else if ($this->input->post('update') == 'y')
{
  // user wants to update
}

else
{
  // user wants to delete
}

// rest of code goes here
```

on each `if` structure, you can take the appropriate actions depending on which button the user pressed

Comment: it's just refreshing;(

Comment: Ok, you need to show us some code (at the very least, the view with the form and the controller/method where the form is processed)